# PhoneGap iOS - media.startRecord file URI not working

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, media

I am trying to use the audio recording as described in the PhoneGap API documentation. But on IOS there seems to be a problem with the file URI for myrecording.wav. I am using the following code to write to a file named myrecodring.wav

```
function recordAudio() {
        var src = "myrecording.wav";
        var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Record audio
        mediaRec.startRecord();

        // Stop recording after 10 sec
        var recTime = 0;
        var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
            recTime = recTime + 1;
            setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
            if (recTime >= 10) {
                clearInterval(recInterval);
                mediaRec.stopRecord();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

i've also tried file://myrecording.wav and file:///myrecording.wav
i've done my test on ios5 iphone 4gs. I get the failure message with code 1 saying "Cannot use audio file from resource...."

Thanks for you help,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get file system:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

Then get the file:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    alert('got FS');
    fileSystem.root.getFile("myrecording4.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
```

Now you can get the file URI:

```
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        alert('File URI: ' + fileEntry.toURI());
}
```